# Error details in release mode (Actionscript)

Tags: actionscript-3, runtime-error

In release mode of my project when an error occurs (on client) and is logged. For instance Error 1009, I do not know which class it came in.

It's a lot harder to debug a 1009 if you don't know which class it came in. Is there any way that when a null or other errors occur. I can at least log the class?

Comment: You are able to do it in the release mode, but only if you have Debugger Flash Player.

Comment: The clients do not have a Debugger Flash Player. That's the issue.

Comment: then he needs to install it or you need to check your code once again.

Comment: I'm working on a web game. I have 100K 'clients' . I cannot ask them to install debug player.

Comment: i have the same task, but at least on my side i know in which component the unknown error appeared. So basically you need to check your code once again. or just install a debug flash player on your machine and run full test round of your web.

Comment: Yeah that's the issue I need to find the class. I've run the tests quite a lot of times. But doesn't happen on my side.

Comment: well i'm using the SWFAddress class, so at least i can identify the main component where error comes from when it comes to the unknown error. But you can do some Log tacking. Basically here i can not offer you any easy solution.

Comment: Yes, I'm doing log tracking. It's a lengthy and tiresome process was wondering if getting a class name was possible. Thanks though

Answer (score 0):

Flash player doesn't provide any additional information for this error. I use a lot of try..catch s and custom stack trace.